# App crashes when attempting to return an array from reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

My web app uses redux to manage state and one of my components (`PostsPreviewsGrid.jsx`) has the following dispatch ([full code](https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/blob/master/web/components/blog/PostPreviewsGrid.jsx)):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateLikes: (postsArr) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'CHANGELIKEDPOSTS', payload: [...postsArr] });
  },
});
```

Here, `postsArr` is an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
  {likedPostId: "abcdef123", liked: 1}
  {likedPostId: "wxyza456", liked: 1}
]
```

The reducer (`postsLiked.js`) is a slice that looks like this ([full code](https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/blob/master/web/reducers/slices/postsLiked.js)):

```
export default function postsLiked(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'CHANGELIKEDPOSTS':
        return [...action.payload];
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

Here, as you can see, the payload being sent is an array. I need to return this array from the reducer slice:

```
return [...action.payload];
```

However, it crashes my app with an invariant error. But if I replace the above statement to return a non-array value, it works just fine:

```
return 'test value`;
```

Also, a `console.log()` in my reducer does display the payload array without any hiccups:

```
console.log('...action.payload', ...action.payload);
```

It's just `return [...action.payload];` that causes the problem.

What am I doing wrong here?

The complete repo for this app is up [here](https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/tree/master/web).
The web app can be run at https://www.schandillia.com/blog (login using Google to reproduce the crash).

Comment: Which component listens to `postsLiked` of redux state. See if its expecting an array. Can you post the entire error .

Comment: The error text says:

```
l(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

But it doesn't say which function.

Comment: Also, I'm reading the reducer state in the `PostPreview` component:

`const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  userInfo: state.userInfo,
  language: state.language,
  postsLiked: state.postsLiked,
});`